# Unity Codeless IAP and iOS: “UnityIAP: Received 0 products”

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I've been working on an `iOS` app that implements in-app purchasing through Unity's codeless `IAP`, and I've been repeatedly running into a series of errors that culminates in the failure of `UnityIAP` to initialize:

```
2018-07-17 11:19:49.534325-0400 myApp[3536:9271265] UnityIAP: Requesting 4 products
2018-07-17 11:19:49.543170-0400 myApp[3536:9271265] UnityIAP: Requesting product data...
2018-07-17 11:19:52.427308-0400 myApp[3536:9271265] UnityIAP: Received 0 products
2018-07-17 11:19:52.447201-0400 myApp[3536:9271265] UnityIAP: No App Receipt found
2018-07-17 11:19:52.453272-0400 myApp[3536:9271265] UnityIAP: No App Receipt found
...
Unavailable product com.myCompany.myApp.myProduct1 -1000000001
...
Unavailable product com.myCompany.myApp.myProduct2 -1000000002
...
Unavailable product com.myCompany.myApp.myProduct3 -1000000003
...
Unavailable product com.myCompany.myApp.myProduct4 -1000000004
...
Purchasing failed to initialize. Reason: NoProductsAvailable`
```

In short, when Unity attempts to initialize using the catalog I defined, it seems to be unable to find the associated products on App Store Connect. I've been through many other threads here and on Unity's website and none seem to hold the answer.

Common suggestions are to

1. Ensure that `IAP` is enabled in the provisioning profile
2. Ensure that the Product ID and Apple ID values on iTunes Connect match those in the Unity catalog
3. Ensure that code is signed using the proper signature
4. Ensure that the product types match (e.g. Consumable, Non-Consumable, Subscription)
5. Ensure that the device is logged in to the sandbox account
6. Ensure that the developer's iTunes account details are set up
7. Submit the app for review

It seems that most others with the same problem failed one or more of the preceding seven points. However, I've done each of the things, and yet the error persists. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Power of posting strikes again. It looks like the `AppleAppStore ID` override in the Unity catalog is supposed to be the `Product ID` field from iTunes Connect, rather than the `Apple ID` field. In this case, it would be `com.myCompany.myApp.myProduct3` rather than `1000000001`. It was a very quick fix. Posting here for others' edification.